# Allow GET request for only certain Group of Users Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am just getting started with Django Rest framework and want to create a feature such that it allows superuser to create a message in admin.py and allow it only to be seen by a certain group(s) ie. "HR","Managers","Interns" etc.

in other words, only a user belonging to "HR" group will be allowed to get data from view assigned to "HR" group by admin. I would like to have only one view that appropriately gives permission.

Something like

```
#views.py
class message_view(APIView):
     def get(request):
        user = request.user
        group = get_user_group(user)   #fetches user's respective group 
        try:
          #if message assigned to 'group' then return API response 
        except:
          #otherwise 401 Error
```

I need some guidance with this.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to define a permission in your app (`<your-app>/permissions.py`) as below:

```py
class HasGroupMemberPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    message = 'Your custom message...'
    methods_list = ['GET', ]

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method not in methods_list:
            return True
         
        group_name ='put_your_desired_group_name_here'
        if request.user.groups.filter(name__exact=group_name).exists():
            return False

        return True
```

Then, import the above permission in your views module (`<your-app>/views.py`) as well as the serializer of the Message model (let's assume MessageSerializer).

```py
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from .permissions import HasGroupMemberPermission
from .serializers import MessageSerializer

class MessageView(RetrieveAPIView):
    # use indicative authentication class
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication, ) 
    permission_classes = (HasGroupMemberPermission, )
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'message_id' 

    def get_object(self):
        """ Do your query in the db """
        qs = Message.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['message_id'])
        return qs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

401 will be returned if user is not authenticated. 403 will be returned if the logged in user is not member of the desired group. 200 will be returned if logged in user is member of the group and the `message_id` exists.